# Access session variables across all controllers in .net core 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have been researching this for a minute but nothing seems to work. I want to be able to set multiple session variables at different points in time and access them across all controllers.

I have tried the below:

I created a base controller and set a public string of the variable I want to access.

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
    {
       public string UserToken
        {
            get
            {
                string token = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUserToken");
                return token == null ? null : token.ToString();
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("SessionUserToken", value);
            }
        }
    }
```

then I inherited from the base controller into my home controller

```
 public class HomeController : BaseController
 { 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
            string userToken = HttpContext.Session.GetString("SessionUserToken"); ;
            if (userToken == null)
              //do something
            else 
             //do something else
    }
       
 }
```

And in another controller as well

```
 public class ProfileController: BaseController
 { 
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel login)
    { 
       Login account = await _Repository.Login(login);
          if(account.succeeded)
           {
               UserToken = account.data;
           }else{
              redirectToAction("Index", "Home");
           }
           
    }
       
 }
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: There are very few legitimate reasons to use `Session`-state thesedays (for one thing, it introduces scaling issues). If you want to store access-tokens to external services consider using ASP.NET Core's built-in support for storing those in its own authentication ticket (so it's stored in the remote user's cookies directly): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/additional-claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: In continuation of @Dai's comment... which problem are you actually trying to solve here? This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your re-creating the authentication system in ASP.NET

I would very much suggest that you consider using the Cookie Authentication system that's already build in. This does NOT require you to use ASP.NET Identity.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-6.0

In your startup file you would have to set

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Forbidden/";
    });
```

Then in your ProfileController you can run the below code to set the authentication cookie.

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("SessionUserToken", account.data)
}, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
    new AuthenticationProperties());
```

Then you can validate access either using the classic attributes like `[Authorize]` or you can check `User.Identity.IsAuthenicated` and when you need the SessionUserToken you can access `User.FindFirstValue("SessionUserToken")`

Comment: Thank you so much for this!. Seems that most articles are very outdated. I only had to make a small adjustment and that was User.Identity.IsAuthenicated instead of User.IsAuthenticated and also [Authorize] instead of [RequiresAuthentication]

Comment: @Kea501 fixed up the code with your mentioned changes, part of it was written from memory late a night :) But glad it helped you out!